# How to disable tap gesture recognizer UIButton for dismisskeyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this code:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dissmissKeyboard))

        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    // Don't handle button taps
    return !(touch.view is UIButton)
}
```

This is a global function!

When I press the login button the keyboard disappears and then I must to press it again to login. Is there a way to avoid this?

I want that when I press login button keyboard not disappear but when I press outside button keybord disappear

Comment: Your question is not so clear. But what i think is when your presss login at first keyboard close and then on second tap your login button function called right ?

Comment: I want that when I press login button keyboard not disappear and button make login but when I press outside button keybord disappear. Actually if I press on Login button keybord disappear and after that I can make login with button. I must press 2 times button to make login because first press button keyboard disappear second press button make login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the delegate.

```
tap.delegate = self
```

Since you haven't add the delegate, your

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
```

method will not execute.

Have a breakpoint there and see that it is execute or not. I don't think so. By adding the delegate that I mentioned earlier will do the trick.

The code will be look like below.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dissmissKeyboard))
tap.delegate = self
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

In the class you should implement the delegate class like below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

Comment: Return this "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'dissmissKeyboard' "

Comment: Please see the updated answer with last code line which implements the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Comment: How does one dismiss a TapGestureRecognizer? After dismissing the keyboard, my CollectionView's didSelectItemAt function won't execute bc it's covered-up/overlaid with the GestureRecognizer.  You would think  view.endEditing might do this automatically, but it doesn't.  Apple